# Does Elven Accuracy work with Oath of Enmity

Tags: dnd-4e, avenger

If a character has activated their `Oath of Enmity`, how does `Elven Accuracy` applied ?

So, e.g. the character rolls two attack dice, and gets a 5 and 7, and they decide to activate their `Elven Accuracy` ...

Do they get just 1 extra roll, or 2 rolls ?

My thinking here is the `Elven Accuracy` states "You make **an** attack roll. Reroll **the** attack roll", and the `Oath of Enmity` is "you make two attack rolls and use either result"

Or could they get 2 rolls from the 'Oath', and then get 2 rolls from the 'Elven'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### You reroll both dice

The answer is already given in the last sentence of the [Oath of Enmity's](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=power&id=3069)<sup>[DDI]</sup> description:

> [...] If an effect lets you reroll an attack roll and you rolled twice because of this power, you reroll both dice.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that ... I should read all the power details at least twice  :-)